# EntityFramework 4 query "sometimes" fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I'm investigating a tricky-to-reproduce bug in my web service. I have proof that a query failed with the following flow:

```
Item c = _itemRepository.GetByCode(code);
if (c == null)
    // this line was hit.
    throw new Exception("invalid code");
```

The specified code was valid during the "failing flow", and when reproduced with the same parameters the query runs fine. My suspect is that, for some reason due to either limited server resources or busy db engine, the query failed to find the relevant content. I thought of a possible expiring timeout, but in that case an exception should have been thrown directly from the `GetByCode` call. Instead, the code executes fine (in roughly 100ms at that) and a null Item is returned. Again, I am 100% positive that the provided parameter is legal and the call should have succeeded: other calls made with the same parameters ran fine.

The repository stores a private `_db DBContext` in its constructor. The called method below runs directly on the context instance.

```
public Item GetByCode(string itemCode)
{
    return _db.Items
        .Include("Field1")
        .Include("Field2")
        .SingleOrDefault(p => p.ItemCode == itemCode && p.Field1.IsReady);
}
```

I'm using EntityFramework 4.0. Any idea about what may be going on is appreciated.